# Convert CSV webservice into multiple year Highcharts line graph

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

I am requesting a webservice, which responds with a CSV file like this (with more monthly data available for the last years). Important for me are the first and last piece of information in the line (aka date and value):

```
2010/01/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,-0.0010074468085106377
2010/02/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.0024117021276595747
2010/03/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.026550000000000004
2010/04/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.08252659574468087
2010/05/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.12837446808510639
2010/06/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.140618085106383
2010/07/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.0668787234042553
2010/08/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.10335744680851064
2010/09/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.08095000000000001
2010/10/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.0400159574468085
2010/11/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.004214893617021277
2010/12/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,-0.0018680851063829788
2011/01/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.0011914893617021279
2011/02/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.003752127659574468
2011/03/01,51.67074582499006,13.789093928493081,0.027225531914893623
```

With this information, I would like to build a Highcharts graphic, which displays a separate line for each individual year. It should look like this:
[image]

My current version adds all data up to a long line - which is nice, but doesn't make the values comparable between the years:

[image]

```
function processData(allText) 
{
    var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var lines = []; var n = 0; var data = []; var dateValue = [];

    for (var i=1; i<allText.length; i++) 
    {
        if (allTextLines[i])
        {
            if ((allTextLines[i].substring(0,2) == "19") || (allTextLines[i].substring(0,2) == "20"))
            {
                dateValue = allTextLines[i].split(",");

                // everything will be concatenated into one single line
                if(Number.isFinite(parseFloat(dateValue[3])))
                {
                    data[n] = [new Date(dateValue[0]).getTime(), parseFloat(dateValue[3])];
                }

                n++;                                
            }
        }                   
    }

    return data;
}
```

Now, what I need is a result which looks like this:

```
series: 
[{
    name: "2010",
    data: [-0.001007447,0.002411702,0.02655,0.082526596,0.128374468,0.140618085,0.066878723,0.103357447,0.08095,0.040015957,0.004214894,-0.001868085]
},{
    name: "2011",
    data: [0.001191489,0.003752128,0.027225532,0.090589362,0.129121277,0.141264894,0.119343617,0.113290426,0.093575532,0.044221277,0.015881915,0.004068085]
}
],
...
```

But I have no idea how my Javascript code must look like, to generate such an outcome. Can anyone give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your data like this :

```
function extract(csv) {
    var rows = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
    var data;
    var series = [];
    var serie = {name: -1, data: []};
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            data = rows[i].split(',');
        if (serie.name === -1) {
                serie.name = data[0].substr(0,4);
        }
        else if (serie.name !== data[0].substr(0,4)) {
            series.push(serie);
            serie = {name: data[0].substr(0,4), data: []};
        }
        serie.data.push(parseFloat(data[3]));
    }
    series.push(serie);
    return series;
}
```

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/mk7x7bbe/

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. Thanks so much! Small problem still on my side, I am trying in vain to resolve: I am using `chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart(}` as I will have multiple charts on my page; and, due to the use of a webservice, I am calling the `extract(csv)` within the `success: function(data)` of that call. I would do that as `var series_return = extract(data);` and then add it `chart1.addSeries(series_return);`. But that doesn't work. I've changed [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/temscLqj/1/) accordingly, to make that clearer.

Comment: I still don't succeed in transforming this into a working example. Especially now, as the data composition goes through a Ajax call with `success: function(data) {}`. I have a call `series_return = extract(csv);` there with `chart.addSeries(series_return);`. But that won't do it. What is wrong? I've updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/temscLqj/3/) to reflect my needs. Thanks for any hints!